# Error in SQL Server when connecting to PowerBI Datamart [Unsupported sql function USER_NAME]

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

I have connected to a Datamart via SSMS. Behind the Datamart is an Azure SQL database.

I am trying to find out my username. I used the following query:

```
SELECT USER_NAME();
```

I get this error:

> Unsupported sql function USER_NAME. Line:1, Position:8

I have combed the internet but I have not come across something that works yet.

Comment: "Data mart" is a rather general term that's unfortunately also used for specific products. To be clear, you're talking about a [Power BI datamart](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/transform-model/datamarts/datamarts-overview), right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I'm referring to Power BI Datamart.

Comment: Although they "speak" TDS and have an SQL endpoint available, the language used is not T-SQL, and as far as I can tell there is as yet no formal documentation on what the language does and does not support. The only thing even close to that that I could find is that there's apparently a `metadata.fn_relationships` function, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/transform-model/datamarts/datamarts-analyze#relationships-metadata), but that incidental mention is the only thing. The language must have a syntax and semantics beyond SQL, they just haven't written it up yet. :P

Comment: That's useful to know. I'm going to try and see if I can contact anyone from the PowerBI dev team about this. Is it correct to say that SQL runs fine but T-SQL functions most likely won't work?. Please feel free to post it as a solution so that I could mark it as an answer.

Comment: What they've apparently done is written their own little engine that parses SQL and likely selectively forwards or translates statements to the underlying Azure instance (or instances?) doing the real work. It's a bit hard to tell from the docs alone exactly how sophisticated it is (that is, what it does and doesn't send to the underlying engine) but apparently, as you've discovered, a query with nothing but a built-in function invocation will not be translated/forwarded. Even though it's in preview I think docs on the language should be there sooner rather than later, but I'm not on the team.

Comment: Please see my updated comment below to the answer. It ended up working in the end. Although I agree more information on Power BI Datamart is definitely needed. I seem to be restricted from creating tables too. I can't grant myself that privilege either. Also I noticed that the tables are simply 'views'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in MS SQL SERVER you must use

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER;
```

The op wrote in the comment, that he needed to close the open query box and open a new one, after that it works, like a charme.

or to get the windows user mame of the logged in user

```
SELECT  SUSER_NAME() LoggedInUser
```

[image: result of the query]

Comment: I tried that and I got the same error. `Incorrect syntax near (. Line:1, Position:12`. Just a note, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: oh sorry, i misread the database you are using, try the changed answer

Comment: I got this error when typing it: `Unsupported sql function SUSER_NAME. Line:1, Position:9`

Comment: both show a result in sql server 2019, all comands run onazure as endpoits.

Comment: The question isn't actually about SQL Server. Power BI Datamarts offer a SQL Server-compatible endpoint (protocol-compatible, at least) but don't actually implement T-SQL directly, just as there are multiple things that "speak" the MySQL or Postgres wire protocols without actually being MySQL or Postgres.

Comment: It worked, it worked `SELECT CURRENT_USER;` worked. I closed the query box and opened it again in SSMS. Ran the query and it returned the user. I'm not sure what was going on there.

Comment: So this answer actually isn't correct.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid no the first answer was already correct. after closing the query box, everything works just fine